# Setting multiple variables from a Execute SQL Task result object with a single row

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have the following sql in an EXECUTE SQL TASK:

```
SELECT [CnxnStrValue1] as INT_Support_CnxnStr
,[CnxnStrValue2] as Lawson_CnxnStr
,[CnxnStrValue3] as Lawson_HRIS_CnxnStr
FROM  [dbo].[InterfaceDBCnxn] 
WHERE InterfaceName = ?
```

The result set is set to an object variable.  I also have three string variables to hold the values and typically I would map them to a For Each Loop Container.  But, in this case, my result set will always only be one row because InterfaceName is the primary key of the table.

Whats is the best way to set the variables with out using a for each loop container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your result set from `Full` to `Single Row`. I use this pattern for my DW loads to get the surrogate key value for my unknown members.

[image]

ResultSet set to `Single row`

[image]

Map your parameters as needed. Here, I have 8 variables that get mapped

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Given your table is `Table` and a column is `Column_name` and `Column_name_two` you can do something like this.

```
SELECT @yourVar = Column_name,
       @yourSecondVar = Column_name_two
FROM Table
WHERE Table_id = 1
```

Comment: Do the parameter need to be set as output?

Comment: I'm assuming you can just do `DECLARE @yourVar type` before the `SELECT`

Comment: Sounds like this should work but I wen with billinkc's solution to keep it simple.